# Replace duplicates value on df subset with Nan but keep rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have seen this question in a few other posts but I can't seem to be applying it to my case.

I have a df that looks like this

```
A       B       C            D      E
--------------------------------------
Mark    NY      Confirmed    Buy    10 
Mark    NY      Confirmed    Buy    22 
Mark    NY      Confirmed    Buy    40 
John    NY      N/A          Sell   55 
John    NY      N/A          Buy    30 
Karl    LA      Confirmed    Buy    22 
Karl    LA      Confirmed    Buy    66 
Karl    LA      Confirmed    Buy    25
```

And I would like to remove the duplicates without loosing the rows to get something like

```
A       B       C            D      E
--------------------------------------
Mark    NY      Confirmed    Buy    10 
                                    22 
                                    40 
John    NY      N/A          Sell   55 
                             Buy    30 
Karl    LA      Confirmed    Buy    22 
                                    66 
                                    25
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.duplicated(["A", "B", "C", "D"]), ["A", "B", "C", "D"]] = np.nan`

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your `pandas.DataFrame` object as follows:

```
import io

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# df format
my_df_str = """A       B       C            D      E
--------------------------------------
Mark    NY      Confirmed    Buy    10 
Mark    NY      Confirmed    Buy    22 
Mark    NY      Confirmed    Buy    40 
John    NY      N/A          Sell   55 
John    NY      N/A          Buy    30 
Karl    LA      Confirmed    Buy    22 
Karl    LA      Confirmed    Buy    66 
Karl    LA      Confirmed    Buy    25 
"""

my_df_str = my_df_str.replace('-', '')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(mystr), sep='\s+', keep_default_na=False)
```

this gave me:

```
      A   B          C     D   E
0  Mark  NY  Confirmed   Buy  10
1  Mark  NY  Confirmed   Buy  22
2  Mark  NY  Confirmed   Buy  40
3  John  NY        N/A  Sell  55
4  John  NY        N/A   Buy  30
5  Karl  LA  Confirmed   Buy  22
6  Karl  LA  Confirmed   Buy  66
7  Karl  LA  Confirmed   Buy  25
```

then I located duplicated values and replaced the 4 columns with `nan`.

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(["A", "B", "C", "D"]), ["A", "B", "C", "D"]] = np.nan # find values where all 4 cols have duplicate
df.loc[df.duplicated(["A", "B", "C"]), ["A", "B", "C"]] = np.nan # find values in this filtered df, where first 3 cols are duplicated
```

which gave me

```
      A    B          C     D   E
0  Mark   NY  Confirmed   Buy  10
1   NaN  NaN        NaN   NaN  22
2   NaN  NaN        NaN   NaN  40
3  John   NY        N/A  Sell  55
4   NaN  NaN        NaN   Buy  30
5  Karl   LA  Confirmed   Buy  22
6   NaN  NaN        NaN   NaN  66
7   NaN  NaN        NaN   NaN  25
```

just to make it exactly like your desired df, I replaced the `nan` values with empty string `""`.

`df = df.fillna("")`

which gave me

```
      A   B          C     D   E
0  Mark  NY  Confirmed   Buy  10
1                             22
2                             40
3  John  NY       N/A    Sell 55
4                        Buy  30
5  Karl  LA  Confirmed   Buy  22
6                             66
7                             25
```

Comment: I guess it does not work in the case of row 4.

Comment: I added `keep_default_na=False` in `read_csv` so `N/A` would not get interpreted as `nan`. Then the result is as desired.

Comment: No, `John  NY       N/A` should not appear in row 4!

Comment: Oops, had not seen that, thanks for the heads up @PaulS